# Codeigniter with jQuery Mobile sometimes returns wrong base_url()

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, codeigniter, jquery-mobile

Good day, fellow coders!

I am currently working on a mobile version of a website. We are initially using Codeigniter as framework, but as for the mobile version, we are asked also to use a bought Mobile Template package that uses jQuery Mobile.

PROBLEM:

By going to other pages (clicking on links via anchor tags, buttons, ajax redirect, etc) errors RANDOMLY occur on the following:

- broken links of images
- broken href links on anchor tags
- going to a wrong controller (page not found)

I have noticed that even if I add in  on every link it goes, the link changes to the current full URL..

EXAMPLE:

I am in

```
http://localhost/m.mysite/dashboard
```

and from that page I am in, if I click on

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url();?>home/login">
```

the URL it will go to will be

```
http://localhost/m.mysite/dashboardhome/login <!-- ERROR -->
```

but if I refresh that page again, I will successfully see no broken links

```
http://localhost/m.mysite/home/login <!-- CORRECT -->
```

If I refresh the site, errors will be gone. Is this because jQuery mobile only do haschange and not refreshing each page?

How come it's like this even if I added `<?php echo base_url(); ?>`

In the `application/config/config.php`, I have also made sure that I did not miss to indicate my base url as `http://localhost/m.mysite/`

Answer (score 0):

Try site_url() instead of base_url(), maybe it would help. There shouldn't be anything wrong with base_url(), but still.

Another thing - could it be something additional in your .htaccess files that makes the redirect? You could check the original link from /dashboard, just hover your mouse on the link and look what browser status bar shows. Or go to View Source.

Comment: Hi! I still am stuck with this. Do you have any solutions in mind? :( I still can't manage to solve this....